# Twitter typeahead not matching correctly when using "remote", but working with "local" JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel-4, twitter-typeahead

I'm creating an autocomplete in Laravel 4 using [twitter typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js), but I'm having problems in the matching process.

The **JS** code:

```
$('#autocomplete').typeahead({
  limit: 20,
  name: 'destinatari',
  prefetch: '{{URL::to("alumni/posta/utenti")}}',
  remote: '{{URL::to("alumni/posta/utenti")}}'
});
```

The **model** populates the array like this:

```
public static function jsonList($idLogged)
{
  $users = DB::table('users_data')
             ->where('userid', '!=', $idLogged)
             ->select('nome', 'nome_2', 'cognome', 'cognome_2', 'userid')
             ->orderBy('cognome', 'asc')
             ->orderBy('nome','asc')
             ->get();
  $i = 0; 
  $ordered = array();
  foreach($users as $u) {
     $ordered[$i]['value'] = $u->nome.' '.$u->nome_2.' '.$u->cognome.' '.$u->cognome_2;
     $ordered[$i]['tokens'] = array($u->nome, $u->cognome);
     $ordered[$i]['userid'] = $u->userid;
     $i++;
  } 
  return $ordered;       
}
```

And my **controller** simply:

```
return Response::json( Users::jsonList($this->userdata->id) );
```

The **returned json** (I see it in Firebug) looks like:

```
[{"value":"Silvia Miriam Abeyta Carretero","tokens":["Silvia","Abeyta"],"userid":"246"},
{"value":"Malak Julia Abreu Garrido","tokens":["Malak","Abreu"],"userid":"198"},{"value":"Aina  Aguado ","tokens":["Aina","Aguado"],"userid":"243"},
{"value":"Jordi  Alarc\u00f3n ","tokens":["Jordi","Alarc\u00f3n"],"userid":"308"},
{"value":"Aaron Nerea Alejandro ","tokens":["Aaron","Alejandro"],"userid":"49"},
{"value":"Alexia  Alem\u00e1n ","tokens":["Alexia","Alem\u00e1n"],"userid":"306"},
{"value":"Salma  Almaraz ","tokens":["Salma","Almaraz"],"userid":"54"},
{"value":"Alma  Almonte Nev\u00e1rez","tokens":["Alma","Almonte"],"userid":"101"},
{"value":"Daniela  Almonte ","tokens":["Daniela","Almonte"],"userid":"184"}
,....other similar results....]
```

The problem is that any letter I type *only the first name in the list gets autocompleted* ("Silvia Miriam Abeyta Carretero") in the input field, but when I type out **in full** any other name (say, "Daniela Almonte") the field isn't completed and the dropdown keeps showing the whole 20 results, without processing of any kind.

I must say, though, that if I click on a name it gets selected correctly (I'm logging the *userid* property of the *datum* ), but still the autocompletion isn't working.

What puzzles me is that If I copy/paste the whole list *directly* in the JS (taken *as is* from Firebug), as `local` property of `typeahead()` (instead of `remote`), everything works fine as it should.

What could be causing this? Is it a Laravel response problem? Or is it the typeahead processor (I believe it's in "transport.js" source file, uses jQuery `$.ajax()`) of the `remote` url?

It seems like the returned JSON is considered as a single entry, i don't know why since it looks correct to me...

Comment: Uhm, care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the typeahead documentation:

```
$('input.twitter-search').typeahead({
    name: 'accounts',
    prefetch: 'https://twitter.com/network.json',
    remote: 'https://twitter.com/accounts?q=%QUERY'
  });
```

As you can see, the remote parameter must contains the URL **with the query parameter**.
PHP side, you have to test if the parameter "q" is set and then adapt your request (with a LIKE statement by example) to correctly filter the list.

Otherwise, you can try to remove this remote parameter, maybe it would work with only the prefetch attribute.

Comment: I omitted it so far since I want a full list anyway, and filter only locally, so I thought it wasn't necessary. Damn me if it was that light mistake...

Comment: So, did it fixed your issue?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had the time to test it before. Yeah, it works: I thought the parameter wasn't necessary but turns out it is indeed. Thank you for pointing me to this silliness of mine, and I thought I read the doc carefully...

Comment: I still cannot award the bounty, need to wait some more time, I'll be done as soon as I'm allowed to :)