# Typeahead remote with Laravel 4 - Individual pieces working I think, but not working together

Tags: php, laravel-4, typeahead.js

I'm relatively green with Laravel and PHP.  I'm learning Laravel by way of the documentation and SO/Google.  I've clicked on every typeahead/laravel question I could find here, and I just can't seem to find an example that quite fits.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20663709/1440617) comes very close.  I actually don't see any glaring differences.  But then again, that OP was having trouble with remote as well.

I think I'm close, as my various pieces seem to be working individually.  Let me explain...

I have a form...

```
<div class="input-group form-group" id="ingredients">
    {{ Form::label('ingredients', 'Ingredients') }}
    {{ Form::text('ingredients[]', null, array(
        'class' => 'form-control typeahead',
        'data-provide' => 'typeahead',
        'data-items' => '10',
        'id' => 'ingredients')
    ) }}
</div>
```

... with the script...

```
<script>
    $('.typeahead').typeahead([
        {
            name: 'ingredients',
            remote: '/recipe/create/%QUERY'
        }
    ]);
</script>
```

`remote:` points to this route

`Route::get('recipe/create/{query}', 'SearchController@searchIngredients');`

Which points to this controller method...

```
public function searchIngredients($query)
{
    $data = array();
    $results = Ingredient::select ('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
    foreach ($results as $result) :
        $data[] = $result->name;
    endforeach;
    var_dump($data);
    return Response::json($data);
}
```

When I enter some text in the form, I do see the browser request:
[image]

If I navigate directly to the remote URL, I do see my `var_dump` as I would expect:

E.g. `/recipe/create/s` shows me

```
array(4) {
    [0] "Sugar"
    [1] "Cheese"
    [2] "Salt"
    [3] "rasins"
}
```

I'm clearly missing something, and I have a suspicion that it's simple, though I could be wrong there too. When I begin typing in the form field, there is no dropdown.

I'm thinking my controller method is never being called when typing, or I would be seeing the `var_dump` with every browser request, right?

If that's the case, am I broken at the `remote:` bit of the script?

---

EDIT

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I am not... console is empty

Comment: Okay, when you click on the request in the inspector (like your picture above), do you see the var_dump?

Comment: @JamieRumbelow I do.  I actually see the `var_dump` and the `json` response.  Edited question to include picture...

Comment: Okay.... and have you tried taking the `var_dump` call out of the controller? Typeahead is expecting valid JSON as a response

Comment: @JamieRumbelow, that did it!  Good lord, here I am trying to check the contents of my variables to figure out where the problem is, and the checking itself is the problem.  /facepalm!  Kind of reminds me of the Schrödinger's cat experiment :)  Anyway, thanks for your help.  Throw that last comment up as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: That sort of thing happens to me all the time - glad you got it fixed :)

Comment: Also, that was a really well asked question, thanks for being so detailed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking `var_dump` out of the controller - typeahead is expecting valid JSON as a response.

Answer (score 1):

This will work and tested:

```
$data = array();

$results = Student::select ('id')->where('id', 'LIKE',$query . '%')->get();
foreach ($results as $result):
    $data[] = $result->id."";
endforeach;
return Response::json($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you could have done

```
$results = Ingredient::select ('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->        

return Response::json($results);
```