# typeahead not working with laravel 4.0

Tags: php, laravel-4, typeahead.js

I am trying to make auto complete feature in laravel 4 using 'typeahead.js'. I saw the vary close question in stackoverflow. below the that link.

[Typeahead remote with Laravel 4 - Individual pieces working I think, but not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886845/typeahead-remote-with-laravel-4-individual-pieces-working-i-think-but-not-wor)

but it not work for me. so I want to find source project like that. anyone can upload. thanks.

Comment: `but it not work for me` That's not really helpful. How? Why? What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: I am a beginner for web development. so I don't know find ajax error. If you can upload your working code, that really helpful me. thank.

Comment: Yeah, sure, let me ask my boss if I can take out a couple hours to code something for you. Brb... Joking aside, open the dev console in your browser (say, F12 in Chrome) and look for errors there

Answer (score -2):

I am so tired to working with 'typeahead.js'. I found best method to create auto sujession in laravel using jQuery UI.

http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/laravel-application-development-cookbook/ch02lvl1sec27

Comment: This isn't really an answer.